# Android OnItemClickListener not working

Tags: android, listview, listener

I'm using android 2.3.3. I set up a layout like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView android:id="@+id/mainList" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And I'm manipulating it with

```
package org.dewsworld.ui;

import org.dewsworld.core.NBConfig;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class NewsBotActivity extends ListActivity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        setListAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                            NBConfig.topics));

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainList) ;
        listView.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() {

        });
    }
}
```

Using eclise IDE, when I setthe OnItemClickListener it gives me the error

```
The method setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (new 
     OnItemClickListener(){})
```

I can't fix this. [I've added an image with the error][image: img][image: img]

Comment: Are you importing AdapterView.OnItemClickListener? If not, try using `new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {`

Comment: `Ctrl+1` might come in handy in eclipse ;)

Comment: import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It seems you have imported the wrong OnItemClickListener, try this one instead, and remove import of android.view.View.OnClickListener

```
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
```

Comment: Wow! It works! But how can I set which Listener to import? Caz, this is auto generated by the eclipse

Comment: Import completion in Eclipse, sorta like ctl-shift-o, usually gives you a list of conflicting imports to choose from.

Answer (score 5):

how about filling in the body of your new object by defining the onItemClick()  function:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id)
{
    // Display a messagebox.
    Toast.makeText(this,"Your Listener Works!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

try using ctrl+shift+o in eclipse to organize all your imports automatically...

Answer (score 1):

Just implement `OnItemClickListener` to your class.

Like This:

`public class ClassName extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{}`