# Android ListView object not liking new onItemClickListener() as argument to setOnitemClickListener()

Tags: java, android, eclipse

So, I am trying to learn some basic android programming and I've hit a roadblock when I've tried to set the onItemClick() method for a programatically generated ListView. The error that eclipse is giving me states, "The method setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type AdapterView is not applicable for the arguments (new onItemClickListener(){})". And I am utterly confused. I have tried cleaning the project several times, on the off chance that there was a problem with it there. I've also tried the advice found in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577848/android-onitemclicklistener-not-working) to no success. Unfortunently that is the only question I've found related to my problem, as most question with onItemClickListener deal with it not getting called properly. I have looked through those questions at the suggested code and tried to make sure my code follows what is suggested. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the offending snippet of code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public ArrayList<ContactData> data;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contact_list);
    data = getContacts(); // creates arraylist for contact data
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (ContactData item: data) {
        names.add(item.getName());
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.textview, names);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    //listView.setClickable(true);
    // set click listener
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.onItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) view;
            String name = textView.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Edit: Having found no luck with eclipse, on a whim I tried the terminal tools that Google provided and tried building my project that way. It worked, so something is screwed up with eclipse. I'm no sure how or what, but everything works totally fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having found no luck with eclipse, on a whim I tried the terminal tools that Google provided and tried building my project that way. It worked, so something is screwed up with eclipse. I'm no sure how or what, but everything works totally fine now. For as far as getting my code to compile and work, it's answered.

Answer (score 2):

It's a minor typo.  Change the line

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.onItemClickListener() {
```

to

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
```

(You missed the capital "O" in OnItemClickListener)

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't fix it. I am still getting the same error, except the o is capitalized in the error as well. Thank you for suggesting something though.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener